# execute many sql statements at the same time with sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, execute, pymysql

I can execute MySQL statements one by one with *sqlalchemy*.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

ipass = "xxxx"
mysql_ip = "xxxx"

link = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:{}@{}:3306/?charset=utf8".format(ipass,mysql_ip))

sql1 = text("use dbname;")
sql2 = text("truncate table table_name;")
sql3 = text("alter table table_name auto_increment=1;")

link.execute(sql1)
link.execute(sql2)
link.execute(sql3)
```

This works fine. I want all three mysql statements to run in one execute command:

```
sql = text("""
use dbname;
truncate table table_name;
alter table table_name auto_increment=1;
""")
result = link.execute(sql)
```

The error message returns:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax...

Is there no way to batch multiple SQL statements in *sqlalchemy*?

How to add `client_flag=CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS` in create_engine statement then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@scrapy, based on [this code](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4277#issue-384642277), you can add `client_flag=CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS` flag this way:

```
from pymysql.constants import CLIENT
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

...

create_engine(
    f"mysql+pymysql://root:{ipass}@{mysql_ip}:3306/?charset=utf8",
    connect_args={"client_flag": CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS}
)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got hit by the same issue some time ago, it’s at the driver level (`pymysql`), you need to add the flag `client_flag=CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS` on the `create_engine` call, see the friendly answer from the maintainer https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/770

Comment: the question was where to put it